# Cronjob not execute sql script

Tags: bash, cron

I have a script called install.sh. This script execute some others script. All work fine just he call a *.sql script. In this case call the script but exit without give an error but don't execute the sql script. Manually, if I call install.sh with an user, all script work correctly.

I create the cronjob with the same user as used to test manually.

Script:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "start"
cd /path/to/script/install.sh
./install.sh
echo "End"
```

Cronjob:

```
01 01 * * * /full/path/to/start_script.sh
```

Comment: Check if all the environment variables are set correctly in your cron job. Usually cron jobs do not call the user's profile.

Comment: I know, I try to add the path into the script but nothing change. How I set the variables in my cronjob??

Answer (score 1):

More trace are needed.

Could you modify your script to generate output in a log file?

```
#! /bin/bash
exec 1>>/tmp/debug.log
exec 2>>/tmp/debug.log
date "+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S ====== S T A R T"
cd /path/to/script/install.sh
bash -x ./install.sh
date "+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S ====== E N D"
```

Wait the next execution and use debug.log file to debug